# Date Vs Name Return Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to return a value based on two cells. If one cell has a date, return nothing. If it has no date, return the other cell.

I've tried `match`, `index`, `or`, `is`, `if`. I just cannot find the right combination.

```
=IF(M3=",>",""),IF(M3="",Blank),IF(OR(m="",F3),"")
```

This would be used in column N.

[image]

Basically, if there is a date in column M, I want to return nothing. If there is no date in Column M, then return Column F. This is probably the most simple thing ever, but I can't get past it.

Comment: `=IF(M3="","",F3)`??

Comment: `=if(isblank(M3), F3, "")`

Comment: In cases where there's no date, what is in the cell? Blank? Text? Etc?

Comment: There's a formula in the cell where the date would be, even if it is blank. Is there any way to circumvent that from showing as a false?   In the case of =IF(M3="","",F3), it returns F3.  In the case of =if(isblank(M3), F3, ""), it returns a blank.

Comment: It depends on what value that formula returns when it is not going to return a date. Check for equality with that.

Comment: The formula produces the date that would be entered in M3.  Under Cancellations, it would be a formula that produces a date.  I've tried taking the formula out and entering just the date, same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(LEN(M3)=0,F3,"")
```

It will solve the issue that **ISBLANK** is not recognizing the `blank` returned by a formula in Cell `M3`.

Next time when you are making a screenshot better to include the Column Headings (A,B,C,D,E, etc.).

Comment: That is it!! Thank you SO MUCH!! Will do!! Have a great day!!

Comment: @MelissaGaynor Glad it helped :) If my answer is working for you just fine, you might want to accept it as the solution by clicking the tick mark under the up-vote and down-vote button?